# Creating View on Another Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to create view on different server is it possible to do so ?
And what will be the syntax for the same ?

Comment: You meant joining table or view between two SQL servers(instance), you may do so using linked server. Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Is this a different physical server running Microsoft SQL Server or a different server - i.e. that is as in PostgreSQL, Oracle, MySQL... ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view on another server by using a linked server.

Working syntax :

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'CREATE VIEW dbo.TestView 
        AS 
        SELECT 1 TestColumn
        '
EXEC LinkedServerName.DatabaseName.sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

More information on Linked Servers can be found, for example, using the following link(can be made using either TSQL or GUI):
[Creating linked servers](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-management-studio/)